# Add ScrollViewer to only one column inside a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I'd like to add a scrollviewer to only 1 column in my grid, so that the left column stay fixed, while the right columns can scroll. Also, my right column is a tabpanel, i'd like to be able to scroll only the content.

This is what i currently have : but the whole page keeps scrolling.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <max:MaxListBox Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" x:Name="lsbYear" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WorkingEntity.PayrollFormulas.Periods}"/>

    <max:MaxTabControl Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
        <max:MaxTabItem FieldDescription="Enum:PayrollProvincesType.Federal">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <!-- content for this tab -->
            </ScrollViewer>
        </max:MaxTabItem>

        <max:MaxTabItem FieldDescription="Enum:PayrollProvincesType.Quebec">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <!-- content for this other tab -->
            </ScrollViewer>
        </max:MaxTabItem> 
    </max:MaxTabControl>
</Grid>
```

Example : 
[image: everything is scrolling, not just the content of the tabpanel]

Comment: What do you mean the whole page keeps scrolling? If I try it with normal TabControl/TabItem, only the content of the TabItem scrolls

Comment: @Domysee Right now the Scrollbar seems to be on the main `Grid` tag

Comment: It should not be. Have you tried scrolling the tab while you are hovering the left column?

Comment: @Domysee It does nothing.

Comment: This has to be a child of another ScrollViewer somewhere in the layout tree for it to do as you describe, Domysee is right.